# How to get unique device hardware id in Android?

Tags: android

How to get the unique device ID in Android which cannot be changed when performing a phone reset or OS update?

Comment: Simply try to load a test add, after it is successfully loaded , you will see your device ID in the logcat.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

**Update: 19 -11-2019**

The below answer is no more relevant to present day.

So for any one looking for answers you should look at the documentation linked below

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids

---

**Old Answer** - Not relevant now.
You check this blog in the link below

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

ANDROID_ID

```
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;

private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                    Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

The above is from the link @ [Is there a unique Android device ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id/2853253#2853253)

More specifically, Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID. This is a 64-bit quantity that is generated and stored when the device first boots. **It is reset when the device is wiped**.

**ANDROID_ID seems a good choice for a unique device identifier**. There are downsides: First, it is not 100% reliable on releases of Android prior to 2.2 (“Froyo”). Also, there has been at least one widely-observed bug in a popular handset from a major manufacturer, where every instance has the same ANDROID_ID.

The below solution is not a good one coz **the value survives device wipes (“Factory resets”) and thus you could end up making a nasty mistake when one of your customers wipes their device and passes it on to another person**.

You get the imei number of the device using the below

```
  TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
  telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId%28%29

Add this is manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Is this remain same even after phone reset or update?

Comment: The IMEI for a handset should not change after the point of manufacture.  That assumes though that the device is a phone - not a good assumption.

Comment: My comment says this is not relevant answer, he might have found this solution on web or already implemented as there are many threads already exists on the stackoverflow itself. But his question says "unique device ID which can't be changed on phone reset or os update"

Comment: @Drc agreed. good point. So my answer is not the best solution in this case

Comment: @PareshMayani agreed. the answer is in the link http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

Comment: @PareshMayani, is UUID number change after phone reset ?

Comment: @ChintanRathod what do you mean by UUID? Are you talking about to create by your own?

Comment: @Raghunandan Nice answer and I believe it is quite relevant to what has been asked here. YOu nicely made the point that ID from 'TelephonyManager' is actually unique but may lead to serious issues with User/Session Management for server. P.S. That bugged device was Motorola Droid 2.

Comment: Do you know how can I obtain the same ID outputted by this directly from my phone? (for example, I wanted to obtain the IMEI i would just type: *#06# )

Comment: Telephony-based ID won't be there on tablet devices

Comment: @Raghunandan android does not allow to access the device id using telephony manager according to recent policy changes in android by google

Comment: @KiranManiya yes i do understand. i will update this post.

Answer (score 31):

I use following code to get Android id.

```
String android_id = Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),
            Secure.ANDROID_ID);

Log.d("Android","Android ID : "+android_id);
```

[image]

Comment: Yes ANDROID_ID is fine but as per the document: ***This is a 64-bit quantity that is generated and stored when the device first boots. It is reset when the device is wiped.***

Comment: Thanks for reply.
But ANDROID_ID changed on device reset.I want id which depends on h/w and doesn't changed on os.

Comment: Do you know how can I obtain the same ID outputted by this directly from my phone? (for example, I wanted to obtain the IMEI i would just type: *#06# )

Comment: Is that android Id unique ?

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin then devices of the same model will give you the same value!

Comment: It's known to be null sometimes, it's documented as "can change upon factory reset". Use at your own risk, and it can be easily changed on a rooted phone.

Comment: then what is unique id for android?

Answer (score 5):

Please read this official blog entry on Google developer blog:
http://android-developers.blogspot.be/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

> **Conclusion** For the vast majority of applications, the requirement is
>   to identify a particular installation, not a physical device.
>   Fortunately, doing so is straightforward.
>
> There are many good reasons for avoiding the attempt to identify a
>   particular device. For those who want to try, the best approach is
>   probably the use of ANDROID_ID on anything reasonably modern, with
>   some fallback heuristics for legacy devices

.