# Device ID Giving null Value

Tags: android

I am trying to get Unique ID`[I.E unique id of a device]` by using below code

```
TelephonyManager tManager;

tManager = (TelephonyManager).getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

String deviceId = tManager.getDeviceId();
```

Where `deviceId` Gives me Unique ID for Android Device. I am not testing this on emulator because in emulator i am getting value `000000000000000`

Any way i am testing it on real devices,and this works fine for mostly all devices , but in some device i am getting value `null`

I have tested this on

```
Samsung Galaxy S3

Samsung Galaxy Tab3

Samsung Galaxy Star

Google Nexus4

Google Nexus5

Google Nexus7
```

In all the devices listed above it gives me correct out put except one Device and that is `Google Nexus7`, in this i m getting value `null`

So, ultimately my goal is to get unique value for each particular device, In case if this code gives me null value than i can try some alternate way

i heard that  `Device MAC Address` is a unique for all devices, But unfortunately it just works on wifi connection.

So is there any other way to get unique value of each particular device?

Thanks Any way

Comment: check this if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869482/how-to-get-unique-device-hardware-id-in-android/16869491#16869491

Comment: what's the reason of down votes? Strange

Comment: You may use [this library](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-BaseLib) to generate a unique ID per device with [Identity.getDeviceId(context)](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-BaseLib/blob/master/Source/src/im/delight/android/baselib/Identity.java) that works in all cases.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You shouldn't really use the ANDROID_ID, you have no real guarantee that it will give you a unique identifier for the device and it is known that some older devices give the value `null`, or as in Moto's case, the same static value across multiple devices. This value also changes when the phone is reset to the factory default, and is super easy to change on a rooted device.

The correct way is to generate your own UUID via.

```
String uudid = UUID.randomUUID()
```

You then save this in your App, for example through a `SharedPreference`. You can then use Google's Android backup storage to retain this identifier even if the user uninstalls your App.

More information on Backup here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html

If you don't take my word for it, you should take Reto Meier's word for it, he is a developer advocate at the Google Android team. This video will explain what I just told you, check out around minute 15, he also specifically instructs developers not to use the `ANDROID_ID`.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=twmuBbC_oB8&list=WL86437554BC3E54B5

Comment: @Aღmirkhan There is a wealth of good information in those Android I/O videos, I recommend taking a closer look at all of them.

Comment: Would you like to give a tutorial link for backup identifier on google's android backup storage?! Thanks