# How to limit my paid app for only one device on same account in Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, android-lvl

I will publish paid app for android and ios. I want that one account can only install and run on one device. Otherwise I want to block the app on first device. Is there any way to do this?

Note: I know there is a lvl for Google Play. But I am not sure, it does this exactly. Sorry for my english.

Comment: on your backend when a user signs in, if there is already a session token for that user destroy it and make a new one, then if the old session token tries to make a request send back a 401 and log them out on the device. then everytime the app opens make a request to validate that the token is good

Comment: But my app doesnt need internet for working. Is there any offline solution

Comment: no way to do it offline, just do the check whenever they are online, and lets be honest that will be most of the time

Comment: Are you trying to prevent someone from installing this app on both an Android and iOS device or are you only trying to prevent them from installing it on 2 Android or 2 iOS devices?

Comment: @TomerShemesh, you are right we can handle from backend but i having one more case in front you,
Example: I have paid app $2.99 and user installing app in "123" device id with "test@test.com" apple id, now user is login in another device with the same apple id, so how i restrict in other devices, as you know Apple allowing to install app up to 5 devices via iCloud or iTunes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you seem to need to do, is to get the device_ID and pair it with the account.That shouldn't be hard.

You get the device ID when your customer registers ,than at login you check the login credentials AND the device ID...

Here's pretty much all you need regarding the device ID (not the login,I trust you can handle it yourself)

[How to get unique device hardware id in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869482/how-to-get-unique-device-hardware-id-in-android)