# How to get a Android System View ID

Tags: android, user-interface, frameworks, system

I find a different problem.
How to get a Android System View ID?
Like time icon, wifi icon ,net icon, power icon at StatusBar?

Comment: :Hope you get your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869482/how-to-get-unique-device-hardware-id-in-android

Comment: your question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

i think you used it -

public String getAndroidId() {

```
    return (Settings.Secure.getString(mActivity.getContentResolver(),
            Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID)
    );
}
```

Comment: Sorry,first of all, thank you very much, but I want to get a System widget id at StatusBar, like wifi icon ,net icon, power icon.